# Can I query on the "Tester" field in TFS

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

The "Tester" field in TFS is different than the "assigned to" field.  To set the "tester" field Microsoft has described how to do it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286739%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Are there other ways of setting that "tester" field?  If I want to write a query to see that field, what is the field called in TFS?

The reason I want to do this is so that I can bulk assign a bunch of tests cases to 1 user based on a specific flag in the test case.

Answer (score 4):

You can not query it using TFS queries because property "tester" belongs not to a *Test Case* work item but to a *Test Point* which

> ...is the pairing of a *Test Case* with a *Test Configuration* in a
> specific Test Suite.
>
> So if you have multiple *Test Configuration* that you want to use when
> you run your test, you have a *Test Point* for each pairing of the
> *Test Case* with a configuration as shown in the following illustration:
>
> [image]

*Source: [How to: View Manual Test Case Results Using Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee843861(v=vs.110).aspx) at Microsoft Developer Network*

The only way to get or/and change the "tester" property, except for using *MTM* of course, is using TFS API.

Here is an example how to get "tester" property of a particular *Test Point*:

```cs
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyConsoleApplication
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(<tfsUri>), new System.Net.NetworkCredential(<tfsUserName>, <password>));
         tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

         var testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
         var TFSproject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(<TFS projectName>);
        
         var plan = TFSproject.TestPlans.Find(<testPlanId>);
    
         var query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE SuiteId = {0}  and ConfigurationId = {1} and TestCaseId = {2}", <testSuiteId>, <testConfigurationId>, <testCaseId>);
         var testpoint = plan.QueryTestPoints(query).FirstOrDefault();

         TeamFoundationIdentity tester;
         if( testpoint != null)
            var tester = testpoint.AssignedTo; // That's kind of funny... the property is called "AssignedTo", not "Tester"
      }
   }
}
```

That means in order to bulk assign a bunch of tests cases to specific user based on a specific flag in the *Test Case* you will have to write console application.

Comment: This looks like what I want.... but when I tried it, the FirstOrDefault() part wont compile.... also the testpoint object doesnt have an "AssignedTo" variable attached.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've just added two missing "using" statements (I'm using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)  when creating this kind of code snippets and sometime forget that it adds some namespaces by default, sorry for that). You have to add some references to your project, too (*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client* and *Microsoft.TeamFoundtation.TestManagement.Client*). The type of *testpoint* is [ITestPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestpoint(v=vs.120).aspx); it definitely has a property *AssignedTo*

Comment: I suppose you have removed "FistOrDefault()" call because it does not compile. The query gives you a [ITestPointCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestpointcollection.aspx) which does not have *AssignedTo* property, of course ;-)